# Incorrect Count with Multiple Joins

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I'm getting an incorrect count when I use multiple 'Joins'. It should only show 3 as the total but it's returning 134 for the total. What's the proper way to use COUNT with multiple 'Joins'?

```
SELECT  r.Field1
      , Total = COUNT(r.Field1)
FROM    Location1.dbo.Table1 r ( NOLOCK )
        JOIN Location2.dbo.Table2 i ( NOLOCK ) ON r.Field1 = i.Field1
        JOIN Location3.dbo.Table3 rt ( NOLOCK ) ON rt.Field1 = i.Field1
                                                   AND rt.Field2 = r.Field2
WHERE   r.Field3 = '40'
        AND r.Field4 = 'H'
        AND r.Field1 = '516'
        AND CONVERT(CHAR(10), r.TIMESTAMP, 101) = CONVERT(CHAR(10), GETDATE(), 101)
GROUP BY r.Field1
```

Comment: What makes you think 3 is correct and 134 isn't?

Comment: Because if I only select r.Field1, COUNT(r.Field) out of the first table **without** the joins the total is 3. I also validated that it should be 3.

Comment: Yes, well with the joins, you get 134 results. Use `SELECT *`, remove the `GROUP BY` and look at the results.

Comment: Why then do you join the `i` and the `rt` tables if they are not used?

Comment: @ypercube Yeah that was my thought... seems to serve no purpose except to get the count of 134 instead of 3... although that seems to be the OPs problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's how joins work. You get the total number of results as a result of the joins. So even if the original table only has one row that matches your criteria, the `COUNT` from a `JOIN` could have hundreds of results due to one-to-many relationship. You can see why by changing your query:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    Location1.dbo.Table1 r ( NOLOCK )
        JOIN Location2.dbo.Table2 i ( NOLOCK ) ON r.Field1 = i.Field1
        JOIN Location3.dbo.Table3 rt ( NOLOCK ) ON rt.Field1 = i.Field1
           AND rt.Field2 = r.Field2
WHERE   r.Field3 = '40'
        AND r.Field4 = 'H'
        AND r.Field1 = '516'
        AND CONVERT(CHAR(10), r.TIMESTAMP, 101) = CONVERT(CHAR(10), GETDATE(), 101)
```

This will return all rows from all tables and you'll see the 134 rows. If you aren't interested in the total, then don't do the join -- since you say that the query without the joins gives you the expected result of 3.

Comment: That makes more sense. I didn't take into account the one to many relationships. I was planning on adding other fields later on from those joins. Thanks for your help!